# WCF basicHttpBinding configuration is being ignored

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm having an issue with my basicHttpBinding configuration in web.config file, all configuration was configured through "Edit WCF configration" VS2013 tool, but when I called method in "WCFTestClient" tool it returned:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded.

I know that my configuration is OK and it's being ignored because when I open that config "WCFTestClient" tool it shows me different values, default values. Then why MS is offering that configuration if it's being ignored brutally, that's stupid, I guess. But the main question would be, how can I resolve it, or to tell him to take my configuration not his, compiled from somewhere?

P.S my Web.config *basicHttpBinding*

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="01:50:00"
      openTimeout="01:50:00" receiveTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608"
        maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

and usage:

```
  <endpoint address="PersonService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BindingConfiguration" name="PersonSvcBasicHttpBinding"
      contract="WebService.IPersonService" />
```

Comment: post your bindings  (web.config)

Comment: You're probably exceeding WCFTestClient's limit, as opposed to that if your service. Have a WCF trace generated to troubleshoot issues like this.

Comment: Have you tried editing the config values in the WCFTestClient tool?  You can do so by right-clicking on the config file in the left hand pane and selecting "Edit with SvcConfigEditor" from the context menu.

Comment: @Tim From post: "I open that config "WCFTestClient" tool it shows me different values" did it it worked, but I don't want to do it from that tool, I wan't to do it from configuration.

Comment: @John - I don't think I understand what you're asking.  The WCFTestClient will generate the config based on the service's metadata - you can then edit that config in the WCFTestClient via the SvcConfigEditor tool.  You could also manually edit the file (you can get its location by right-clicking on the config file and selecting Copy Path).  But any changes you make manually may get overwritten later.

Answer (score 0):

Usually having both `maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"` works for me.